# jstree - changing icon ( setting the types plugin )

Tags: icons, jstree

I'm using jstree with database, and the schema is almost same as the demo in jstree.com, just adding some fields to "data table".

Fields of "data table": id, nm, dept, types, phone, desc ( adding some fields ).
Fields of "structure table" : id, lft, rgt, lvl, pid, pos ( same as the demo )

What I'd like to do is to change icons depending on the value of the "types" which is one of the "data table" fields.

For example,
 if the value of types is 'a', the icon is 'a.gif',
 if it is 'b', the icon is 'b.gif'
 ...

How should I set the types plugin? or something else to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your defaults icon

```
$("jstreeDiv").jstree({
    plugins: ["types"],
    types: {
        "a": "class_a",
        "b": "class_b",
        ...
        ...
    }
```

class_a, class_b are css classes where you can define the path of your gif.

```
#class_a: {
 background: url('/path_to_your_gifs')
```

Hope this helps.